# How to center multiple divs in other div vertically and horizontally with multiple lines of divs made by clear: both?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="letter1">T</div>
  <div id="letter2">H</div>
  <div id="letter3">A</div>
  <div id="letter4">T</div>
  <div id="letter5" style="clear: both;">W</div>
  <div id="letter6">O</div>
  <div id="letter7">R</div>
  <div id="letter8">K</div>
  <div id="letter9">S</div>
</div>
```

As you can see I have a string divided on characters, each character in another div. I want to have each word in separate line, each centered horizontally. Take under consideration `clear: both;` to start new line. Vertical alignment would be nice but is not necessary. The number of words (lines) and letters vary depending on the situation.

All the guides I have found about centering tell about centering multiple divs, but they are in one line or are centered after free break line (there is no space for next div in line so it takes next line with remaining divs and center the line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap each set of letters (word) in its own div? Not sure what you're trying to achieve really, give us a bit more to go on.

EDIT. Added code example after, for clarity.

```
<div>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>p</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>y</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to hide each letter so it looks like underscore sign and depending on the situation i can reveal mystery after  underscore sign and show real letter. That's why each letter is separated. I did each word in div. It works fine but i have hoped there is better way

Comment: A better way how? A containing div for each word and a span for each letter is what I would do. There's nothing wrong or incorrect about that approach.